# ag-Grid Master / Detail - Row Selection

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

**Goals**

I am trying to add row selection functionality which is connected between the master grid and detail grid.

- When a checkbox on a master grid row is selected, I want to select all the checkboxes in the associated detail grid.
- When a checkbox on a master grid row is deselected, I want to deselect all the checkboxes in the associated detail grid.
- When only partial checkboxes inside of a detail grid are selected, I want the master grid row to show a partial selection icon in the checkbox.
- I want to keep count of how many items were selected in all of the detail grids

---

**Questions/Problems**

All of this functionality already exists for [Groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-groups-checkbox-selection), but I cannot get it to work for Master/Detail. I've tried adding in the line that I believe should add this for Groups `cellRendererParams: {checkbox: true}`, but that does nothing for the detail grid.

I've also tried implementing the functionality myself, but I hit a couple of roadblocks.

1. I don't know how to set the partial-checkbox icon manually or if that's even possible.
2. I implemented the onSelectionChanged event handler for the detail grid, but inside of the function it looks like I can't access the Angular component context to update the count of selected items. Not sure how to pass in the context `this`.

---

**Code that I have working so far:**

When a checkbox on a master grid is selected/deselected, the checkboxes in the associated detail grid are all selected/deselected.

```
  public onMasterRowSelected() {
    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(masterRowNode => {

      if(masterRowNode.isSelected()) {
        this.gridOptions.api.getDetailGridInfo(`detail_${masterRowNode.id}`).api.selectAll();
      } else {
        this.gridOptions.api.getDetailGridInfo(`detail_${masterRowNode.id}`).api.forEachNode(detailRowNode => detailRowNode.setSelected(false));
      }

    });
  }
```

Added the onSelectionChanged() event listener for the detail grid.

```
constructor() {
  this.gridOptions = {
    ...
    detailCellRendererParams: {
        getDetailRowData: function(params) {
          params.successCallback(params.data.items);    // Defines where to find the detail fields out of the rowData object
        },
        detailGridOptions: {
          rowSelection: 'multiple',
          defaultColDef: {
            sortable: true
          },
          getRowNodeId: function (rowData) {
            return rowData.id;      // detail items are indexed by id field
          },
          onSelectionChanged: function (params) {
            console.log(this);      // I expected this to print out my Angular component object, but instead it prints out this.gridOptions.detailCellRendererParams.detailGridOptions
            console.log("TEST");    // I know that this function is successfully being called because this line is printed
            this.selectedItems = 0;
            params.api.forEachNode(detailRowNode => {
              if(detailRowNode.isSelected()) {
                this.selectedObs++; // I believe that this would work if I had access to the correct "this" context
              }
            });
          },
          columnDefs: [
            {headerName: 'Column 1', field: 'column1', checkboxSelection: true},
            {headerName: 'Column 2', field: 'column2'},
          ]
        }
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/0GvgbXb1CHEr90ax) Plunker from ag-Grid. Doesn't this solve your first 3 problems?

Comment: @Viqas yes that does solve pretty much everything I need, but unfortunately that is for Groups and not for Master/Detail grids. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to do the same thing, but for master/detail grids.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Angular example where you can push the parent component as a reference to the detail grid and set it as its context.   Doing this allows you to register a component method  as a callback for the detail grid's onRowSelected method.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-detailrow-selectcallback?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Move the `onSelectionChanged(params)` function to the same level as the `detailCellRendererParams` object.

```
internalOnSelectionChanged(params) 
{
    this.detailGridApi = params.api;
    this.detailGridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    console.log(this);
}
```

Then, on the `onSelectionChanged`, do this:

```
onSelectionChanged: this.internalOnSelectionChanged.bind(this);
```

This solved my issues that were very similar to yours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Derick. I've edited your answer to improve the formatting using Markdown syntax. Please review my edits so you can format future posts correctly.